# Meteor and Azure Blob storage

Tags: node.js, azure, meteor, azure-blob-storage, node.js-stream

I am looking for a way to uploading files to Azure Blob Storage. 
I found [azure-storage](https://www.npmjs.com/package/azure-storage) npm package. 
But I'm having a problem with '***createBlockBlobFromStream***' method.

I dont know how create stream from Uint8Array.

```
 xhr.onload = function (e) {
                    if (this.status == 200) {

                        // Note: .response instead of .responseText
                        const blob = new Blob([this.response]);
                        console.log(audios[i].file);
                        const reader = new FileReader();

                        reader.onload = function () {
                            const data = new Uint8Array(reader.result);
                            Meteor.call('uploadFilesViaSDK', data);
                        };

                        reader.readAsArrayBuffer(blob);
                    }
                };
```

I`m trying to migarate files from S3 to Azure blob. Thats why I dowload files from S3, and than read it as ArrayBuffer and convert it to Uint8Array.
And now I am looking way how to upload this data to azure via azure.createBlockBlobFromStream meyhod. 
Specifically, I need an example of creating a stream from Uint8Array.

I'll be grateful for any answer

Comment: I answered a similar question a few days ago - https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44952566/how-do-i-transfer-base64-data-into-a-readable-image-stream-without-saving-locall. There I created a stream from Buffer. See if this helps you.

Answer (score 0):

In addition to an approach provided by Gaurav, once you created a stream from Uint8Array by using [`streamifier`](https://www.npmjs.com/package/streamifier), you can use [`createWriteStreamToBlockBlob`](http://azure.github.io/azure-storage-node/BlobService.html#createWriteStreamToBlockBlob__anchor) function to write to a block blob from a stream. With that you are able to transmit stream by calling `.pipe()`:

```
streamifier.createReadStream(new Buffer(uint8)).pipe(blobSvc.createWriteStreamToBlockBlob('mycontainer', 'test.txt'));
```