# Uint8array to readable stream in nodejs

Tags: javascript, node.js, azure, mean-stack, node-streams

I am using a node js api service with an angular front-end. I have a feature where I would need to migrate some documents from google drive to azure storage. I have implemented the azure ***blobService*** interactions in node. I use an XHR request to download the document in angular from google drive, convert it into a Uint8array before passing it to the node js service for upload into azure. I am using the method ***blobService.createBlockBlobFromStream()*** to upload into azure. This needs a readable stream as an input parameter. I am new to node js and node streams. How do I convert my Uint8array object into a readable stream? If not a Uint8array, could I use another type to make the conversion easier? I have pasted the code below. Thanks in advance for all the help...

**Angular Code**

```
function requestXHR1(url, accessToken, fileId, type) {
                var xmlHttpReq = new XMLHttpRequest()
                xmlHttpReq.onload = function () {                       

                    uploadBlob(fileId, type, new Uint8Array(xmlHttpReq.response))
                        .then(function (data) {
                            migI++;
                            console.log("total: " + migI + ", uploaded fileId " + fileId);
                        },
                        function (error) {
                            console.log("error uploading fileId " + fileId);
                        });

                }

                xmlHttpReq.open('GET', url, true);
                xmlHttpReq.setRequestHeader('Authorization', 'Bearer ' + accessToken);
                xmlHttpReq.responseType = 'arraybuffer';



                xmlHttpReq.send(null);

}

function uploadBlob(fileName, contentType, file) {
        return $http({
            method: 'POST',
            url: config.baseUrl + 'uploadfile',
            data: { fileName: fileName, contentType: contentType, file: file },
            headers: {
                'Content-Type': 'application/json; charset=utf-8'
            }
        }).then(function (data) {
        }, function (error) {
        });
}
```

**Node.js Code**

```
function uploadBlob(req, res) {
  var blobSvc = azure.createBlobService(config.azureStorageAccount, config.azureSharedKey);
  var fileStream = ConvertToReadableStream(file); //How do I write this function?

  blobSvc.createBlockBlobFromStream(config.azureContainer, req.body.fileName, fileStream,
    req.body.file.length, { contentType: req.body.contentType, blockSize: customBlockSize }, function (error, result, response) {
        if (!error) {
            console.log("blob uploaded");
            res.status(200).send("success");
        }
        else
            res.send("failure");
    })
}
```

Comment: I answered a similar question a few days ago - https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44952566/how-do-i-transfer-base64-data-into-a-readable-image-stream-without-saving-locall/44953589#44953589. There I created a stream from Buffer. See if this helps you.

Comment: Thanks @gaurav! The streamifier works very well.